# How can I send a token from my website to another website

Tags: javascript, php, server

I have a token I have generated on my website for a different server to use with their client.

How can I get this token from my website to another website?

Token could look like: `5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592`

PHP (example):

```
$token = md5(uniqid()); //this is not how my token is actually generated
```

I was thinking to make my site generate a page and reading that page from another website with iFrame, but now I'm considering the use of cookies.

Does anyone know how I can send this token (cookie or otherwise) to another website?

Comment: Try adding it to the URI? For example http://anotherwebsite.com/file.php?tkn=5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592. In file.php, store the tkn in a session/cookie

Comment: yes but if i stored the tkn wouldnt that be putting the cookie on the clients browser registered to my domain? This is being done in a separate window.

Comment: I mean let anotherwebsite.com store the tkn in a cookie/session. By the way cookies are always stored on the clientside, so your iframe solution could work..

Comment: Yeah but how would i get the data to store into the session / cookie? (i decided i will be using a cookie)

Comment: @RichardGrant `document.cookie=...`(js) or php [`setcookie(...)`](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/set-cookies.shtml)

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question; my idea was to do some redirect from mysite.com to anothersite.com/f.php?tkn=b5t6yu7kj8..., and let f.php store the ?tkn (using $_GET) in a cookie

Comment: I'm suggesting simple REST api. Client server then should obtain token via curl or file_get_contents.